# How to clear the input field completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two fields which appear as the data is already entered before:

[image]

On certain condition an `if` condition is called and these value needs to be cleared. I tried  to pass blank string inside `val()` so that it becomes empty 
but it is not working, data is still displayed:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 fromDates" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;">
   <label for="fromDate">From Date</label>
   <input type="text" id="assessFrom" required="" name="assessFrom">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 toDates" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;">
   <label for="fromDate">To Date</label>
   <input type="text" id="assessTo" required="" name="assessTo">
</div>
```

```js
if (assessmentType == "firm" || assessmentType == "product") {
  $('.fromDates').val('');
  $('.toDates').val('');
}
```

Comment: codepen or jsfiddle link please ?

Comment: you can use a cleverer selector which will get the inputs inside your classes, like: `$('.fromDates input')` instead of `$('.fromDates')`.

Comment: Target the input field rather than your div container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.fromDates` and `.toDates` are `div` elements which have no value.

Instead you need to clear the value of the `input` elements within them:

```
if (assessmentType == "firm" || assessmentType == "product") {
  $('.fromDates input, .toDates input').val('');
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `id` on the inputs directly:

```
if (assessmentType == "firm" || assessmentType == "product") {
  $('#assessFrom, #assessTo').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you have Id why you are using class to clear the data from input field,

```
$('#assessFrom').val('');
$('#assessTo').val('');
```

and if you still want to use javascript

```
document.getElementById('assessFrom').value = '';
document.getElementById('assessTo').value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector as input elements

```
$('#assessFrom').val('');
$('#assessTo').val('');
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope the below code will solve the issue, you can change the if condition based on your condition.

```js
function check(){
  if(true){
   var item = document.getElementById("assessFrom");
   item.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 fromDates" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;">
   <label for="fromDate">From Date</label>
   <input type="text" id="assessFrom" required="" name="assessFrom" value="08-07-2018">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 toDates" style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;">
   <label for="fromDate">To Date</label>
   <input type="text" id="assessTo" required="" name="assessTo" value="12-01-2018">
</div>

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but there's a couple of code smells here; the `onclick` attribute, the `if (true)`